# Installing OpenJDK-7 in Xubuntu Using apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, java, apt-get

I am pulling my hair out trying to install openjdk-7 properly in Xubuntu using apt-get.  It seems the version of java I get does not work with the version of javac.  This is what I have in Xubuntu:

```
chris@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
...
Setting up openjdk-7-jre-lib (7~b147-2.0-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Setting up libaccess-bridge-java (1.26.2-6) ...
Setting up icedtea-7-jre-jamvm (7~b147-2.0-0ubuntu0.11.10.1) ...
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10) ...
...
chris@ubuntu:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
...
chris@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
...
chris@ubuntu:~$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_147
```

I'm not a Linux or Java expert, so I wrote the HelloWorld program and tested it on my mac before trying it in the Ubuntu appliance.  I have:

```
---------------------------------------------------
// Hello World!

public class HelloWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Hello, world.");
        }
}
---------------------------------------------------
Chris-mac:~ Chris$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_29
Chris-mac:~ Chris$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_29"
Chris-mac:javaprac Chris$ java HelloWorld
Hello, world.
Chris-mac:javaprac Chris$ clear
```

That looks good, but switching back to Ubuntu, recompiling, and trying to run the same program produces:

```
chris@ubuntu:~$ javac HelloWorld.java 
chris@ubuntu:~$ java HelloWorld 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: HelloWorld : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: HelloWorld. Program will exit.
```

Any ideas?  All I want to do is get openjdk-7 working on the Xubuntu box.  Am I right that the problem is the different versions of java and javac I am getting using apt-get?

Comment: What do you get when you run `update-alternatives --config java`?

Comment: That is the answer.  I needed to switch to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're compiling for Java 7 and running in Java 6:

```
...
chris@ubuntu:~$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
...
chris@ubuntu:~$ javac -version
*javac 1.7.0_147*
...
```

It's why you're getting a class versioning problem:

```
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

I would start off with **which java** and **which javac** to start to track down where each are being run from. My guess is that you need to update **JAVA_HOME** and your **PATH** to have **java** run from the same path as **javac**.